Kali VMware Workstation crashed after upgrading and follow-up fixes. A Public Discussion
When I tried to update Kali Linux 2022.4 to the latest version (2024.2) I had the following errors:
sudo apt-get update

…File has unexpected size (47280544 != 47280534). Mirror sync in progress?

But it was fixed by
sudo apt-get clean then
sudo apt-get update (no problem further regarding above errors)

sudo apt-get update && apt -y full-upgrade

then it failed around 98% to 99% to complete by having following errors when attempting to update again:
An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error...

The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY...

The following signatures were invalid...
Failed to fetch..
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead..

It was fixed by the following steps:
wget -q -O https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add

There is another workaround which I have not yet attempted so far:
wget --no-check-certificate http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-keyring_2022.1_all.deb

sudo apt install ./kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb

sudo apt-get update && apt -y full-upgrade (after fixing)

It was completed to 100% but crashed before completion of unpacking all the packages.
After that, my kali system almost froze and I accidentally clicked the log out button (perhaps a reboot would fix it).
The system rebooted, but before the login screen appeared a cursor kept blinking behind the black screen and nothing appeared. It was fixed and the system recovered as:

Either Ctrl + Alt + F1 to F6 or Alt + F1 to F6 until appear login status in the black screen.
Choose root as login
Type dpkg --configure -a (this halted due to lot of errors)
apt-get autoremove
apt --fix-broken install
reboot (this fix all after that! meaning successfully upgraded from 2022.4 to 2024.2)

After Login to my Kali Machine, there were some other problems like replacement of the default Xfce desktop environment by Xterm ! Tor Browser was removed, WPScan does not run as usual, has dependency issues etc. ( which will do later)
I do not want this issue anymore if  I will update another Kali Linux Version like 2022.4.
Are there any safe methods to upgrade?
Should it be correct to type first  the following, just after the system crashed?
dpkg --configure -a and apt --fix-broken install, before log out ? 

If that is possible in the terminal before the reboot.
Kali Vmware Workstation 16.X.X Pro, 128GB HDD, and 8GB RAM.

Kali Linux is a rolling-release distribution that updates quite frequently. If you want to keep updating an existing installation (as opposed to making a complete reinstall), you should update it way more often than once in about 1.5 years.
The Kali project seems to be producing a major release about four times a year, and minor releases weekly - so you should be updating at least quarterly, or even monthly or weekly if you can.
If you are more than one major release away from the "up-to-date" state, the probability of encountering problems on update will increase along with the number of major releases you'll be skipping over.
From 2022.4 to 2024.2 is a jump of 6 major releases (or 7 if you count the 2023.2a release). With such a large jump, problems on update are expected and a complete reinstall might be a better idea.
Generally, distributions will only test upgradeability from each major release to the next one. I could not easily find a specific statement about how (or if!) Kali project tests their release upgrades. But I would expect a jump of 6 major releases to be completely untested by the Kali project.
